# bash read returns with exit code 1 even though it runs as expected

Tags: linux, bash

I have this construct to initialize a variable with the contents of a file:

```
echo "yyy" > xxx
read -r -d '' PAYLOAD <<< $(cat xxx)
echo $?
echo $PAYLOAD
```

This results in:

```
1
yyy
```

Why is read returning 1? This is breaking my script, because I run with `set -e`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`read` is returning 1 because it returns `0` only when end-of-file is not encountered.

As per `help read`:

```
Exit Status:
The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered
```

You don't even need a `read` here, just use `$(<file)` to read the file content into a variable:

```
echo "yyy" > xxx
payload=$(<xxx)
echo $?
echo "$payload"
```

It is advisable to not use all uppercase variable names in order to avoid clash with ENV variables.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. And thanks for the pro-tip. I would still be interested in knowing why read returns 1 though.

Comment: !! I did not even know the `help` command. I thought the only way to get help about bash builtins was to do `man bash` or `read --help`, which is not giving me much. What is this help command? Bash builtin? Yepp, as per `type help`: `help is a shell builtin`

Comment: But really, `read --help` should give me the same as `help read`

Comment: You can run `help help` to get more info on `help builtin` :)

Comment: Recursive help!

Comment: I would like to know when the end of file character is not encountered, is there a sample command where `read` returns zero?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov could do something awful like `read -r -d '' PAYLOAD < <(cat xxx;printf "\0")`

Comment: The POSIX spec defines a line as a sequence of characters that ends with a linefeed, which is *not* optional at the end of the file. A common problem for Windows users is attempting to read the final line of a non-POSIX text file.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the correct answer here is that `read` fails because it did not encounter a delimiter before EOF.

Because you set the delimiter to be the empty string (`-d ''`), read will fail to find that and will exit with `1`. It will still read everything, but it only does this because it can't find the delimiter. That's why it appears to have worked, but seems to have failed also.

A trick proposed in [another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265195/44793) answer is to use a while loop/if statement. So, something like this:

```
if read -rd '' PAYLOAD; then :; fi <<< $(cat xxx)
```

Or (shorter)

```
if read -rd '' PAYLOAD; then :; fi < xxx
```

Should be enough to prevent the shell from seeing the exit code of the `read` command.

Sources: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265151/44793